# Where is the FiPy "base directory"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, fipy

I have recently installed the FiPy package onto my Macbook, with all the dependencies, through MacPorts. I have no troubles calling FiPy and NumPy as packages in Python.

Now that I have it working I want to go through the examples. However, I cannot find the "base directory" or FiPy Directory in my computer.

How can I find the base directory? 
Do I even have the base directory if I have installed all this via Macports?

As a note I am using Python27.

Please, help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the FiPy docs (http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/README.html):

> When references are made to file system paths, it is assumed that the current working directory is the FiPy distribution directory, refered to as the “base directory”, such that:
>
> examples/diffusion/steadyState/mesh1D.py
>
> will correspond to, e.g.:
>
> /some/where/FiPy-X.Y/examples/diffusion/steadyState/mesh1D.py

This just means the working directory if the FiPy repository is cloned or tarball unpacked and then the directory is changed to `fipy/`. It will have `setup.py` and `examples/` in there. If you install FiPy without cloning or using the tarball (e.g. using pip instead) the distribution directory (base directory)  won't be readily available.

It isn't the path returned from `import fipy; print(fipy.__file__)`. That's the installation path.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import FiPy
print FiPy.__file__
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this and get a path the ends as, "/__init__.pyc" What do I do with this path?

Comment: Still not sure what to do. More help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The .pyc file is the python compiled bytecode file. What you want is the path that contains that file.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had the same issue with Ubuntu I post this here.
If you have installed it using miniconda or anaconda, it will be:

`/home/username/miniconda<version>/envs/<name of the environemnt you installed fipy in>`
if you get the error that fipy module not found, you dont need to export the path but you just need to:
`conda activate <nameOfEnvironment you installed fipy there>`